# Check if some Checkboxes are selected or not selected with selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to check if some Checkboxes are selected or not selected with selenium WebDriver.

Thant is what I did.

```
        if (driver.findElement(By.id("olVizAdminCad:IconLink:mucl403470UG1")).isSelected())
    {
        System.out.println("is selected");  
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("is not selected");
    }
```

The problem is that, it is printing "not selected" when it is actually selected. So I guess I am getting some problems with the "if".

In this link http://www.m-i-u.de/display-i94106bkffbp.html I show you an image of a part of the code. This part corresponds to one single Checkbox of all that I have.

The ID of the element may look like a dynamic ID, but not, it doesn´t change.

Apparently it should work. But it doesn´t, so can anybody say any advice?

Thanks a lot
Pablo

Comment: is the element locateable by id ?

Comment: Eugene what you mean with changing the Id? If I change the Id it won´t work. I mean, the element will not be found, and the displayed message will be "is not selected".

Aura I am not sure when an element (which has an Id) is or not locateable. How can I know it? Just trying whether it works or not?

Answer (score 3):

`WebElement.isSelected()` is only applies to input elements according [the selenium documentation](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isSelected())

In your case your tag is `a`, you should check the child img tag in order to determine if your custom checkbox is checked or not.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but since I have 3 Checkboxes and the tag of everyone of them are the same ("a"). I should do something more to locate each element right?
For example if I only write this:if (driver.findElement(By.tagName("a")).isSelected()). the code won't find the correct checkbox.

Comment: No, the way you locate your element is right. The problem is that you can't call `isSelected` method on a non `input` tag. Try to check the `src` attribute of the child img tag in order to know if it matches checked or not checked.

Comment: But if I do it like this: if (driver.findElement(By.tagName("a")).isSelected()), I am using an input tag. But the point is that there are several element whose tagName is "a". Could you please how can I use this src attribute? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (driver.findElement(By.id("olVizAdminCad:IconLink:mucl403470UG1")).getAttribute("checked") != null)
    {
        System.out.println("is selected");  
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("is not selected");
    }
```

Update:

I apologies for any Syntax errors, I don't work in Java, but you can see what i'm getting at here. I also cannot see in the HTML you posted any checked attribute being set, How does the UI know it has been checked? I'm just completely guessing here:

```
List<WebElement> listIds = driver.findElements(By.xPath("//a[contains(@id,'olVizAdminCad:IconLink:muc')]"));
Map<String, String> checkedItems = new HashMap<String, bool>();

for(Iterator<WebElement> i = listIds.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) 
{
    String item = i.next();
    if(item.getAttribute("checked") != null)
    {
        checkedItems.put(item.getAttribute("id").toString(),true);
    }
    else
    {
        checkedItems.put(item.getAttribute("id").toString(),false);
    }
}
```

You can then use the checkedItems to see what has been checked and not depending on their id?

Update 2:

Ok! it's a fake checkbox! it's using images to change the UI...

```
List<WebElement> listIds = driver.findElements(By.xPath("//a[contains(@id,'olVizAdminCad:IconLink:muc')]/center/img"));
Map<String, String> checkedItems = new HashMap<String, bool>();

for(Iterator<WebElement> i = listIds.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) 
{
    String item = i.next();
    if(item.getAttribute("src").contains("checked"))
    {
        checkedItems.put(item.getAttribute("id").toString(),true);
    }
    else
    {
        checkedItems.put(item.getAttribute("id").toString(),false);
    }
}
```

Basically you can use the `Element.getAttribute("src").contains("checked")` to identify if it's checked and you can just change it to `item.getAttribute("src").contains("unchecked")` to check if it's unchecked.

Comment: It still doesn't work. Maybe it would be a good idea to try to locate the element using something different to the Id?
I am actually a bit confused. I don't know why the location by Id works sometimes and sometimes not. I guess I get it with the experience.

Comment: Can you post the HTML and then I can update my answer to reflect a better way to find the element.

Comment: Yes, I attache a photo of the interesting part (I think) of the code.
http://www.m-i-u.de/display-i94110b02muf.html
It shows the part where the 3 Checkboxes are defined

Comment: And you need to check if all 4 checkboxes are checked?

Comment: I have to check all of them. which one is checked and which one is not, and print for example Checkbox1 is checked, Checkbox2 is not checked...

Comment: @pablocasanovas I have updated my answer but I cannot see anywhere in the HTML where the checked attribute is being set. I'm trying! :)

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I just realized that the problem is not locating the object. Because I did that: driver.findElement(By.id("olVizAdminCad:IconLink:mucs72214OFFICE1")).click(); and it checks and unchecks the checkbox without problems.
So I think the problem might be ob the method isSelected. As I read before. Is it not possible to use isSelected if I am locating the object by Id?

Comment: @pablocasanovas The problem is finding if that element has anything in the DOM to tell the browser that is has been checked. For example a usual checkbox that would be checked: `<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Box1" checked> Box1<br>`. Can you post some HTML of a single checkbox that you have checked?

Comment: I have 3 CheckBoxes. I checked the first one and then I unchecked it. I took photos in both cases, so in the following links you can see what exactly have changed.The parameters that change are href, src, alt and title. In this link you see the checked checkbox http://www.m-i-u.de/images-i94113b6btch.jpg and in this link you see when it is unchecked http://www.m-i-u.de/images-i94114bpdyfc.jpg

Comment: @pablocasanovas updated the answer with hopefully the final solution.